# Creating a Voting System based on Categories in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, wordpress

I want to create a voting system in `wordpress`. I know there are number of wordpress plugins for voting, and I can also code for voting without plugin using `post_meta` that anyone can do right.

But here, I want something different. I have a star selection voting, that a star can appear in different categories. So star's votes should be counted on categories. I have no idea how I can set up db table, or utilize `post_meta` for this.

To be clear here is the full scenario:
I have a post type 'nominees', and custom taxonomy 'nomination_cat', terms like, best actor, best comedian, etc.

Each actor has their own profile, also I can assign an actor to multiple cats, like best actor, comedian.

On front end I am able to show the nominees under different cats, and each profile on font-end has a voting button, so voting should be calculated differently on each category. I think, you got the idea.

Is there a way to do this, preferably without plugin. Even just an idea will be appreciated.

NB: Actors ate stored in a CPT 'Nominees', so I have, Nominee ID (post_id) in wp_post table and 'term_id' in wp_terms table.

Only logged in voters are allowed to vote, so a voter can vote only once.

Comment: You are saying with such confidence that you can code this system without plugin, than you must have much knowledge to sort this out.. take a table with fieilds `id,actor_id,category_id,vote`.. and if you get vote with same `category_id` and `actor_id` than increment the vote...

Comment: and if you want to track about voters as well than take another field `voter_id` and dont increment the vote value, instead everytime insert new entry.. so you can avoid users putting multiple votes

Comment: @NishantSolanki Ofcourse I want to track Voters, as I said I am using WP, so actor_id is some what post_id of a CPT, inside wp_post table. and category_id in another table WP_Terms.. So in Wordpress How can I get these values set up when a nominee is posted.???

Comment: take the table pk in which relation between your post_id and wp_terms (actors and categories). so you just need to save that `primary_key of relational table, voter_id and vote` in your votes table...

Comment: and for allowing only for logged in users than you can use `session`